# Estimating Histogram with Count Sketch

Tags: algorithm, histogram, probability-theory

Count Sketch is an algorithm that uses minimal resources to approximate the number of occurrences of elements in a multiset. I'm interested in using it to build a histogram, although it's a histogram where the buckets are frequency with which the element occurs. However, all of the information I can find only shows how to use count sketch for looking up the number of occurrences of an element at the end. For example, let's say I have the following data:

```
[1,2,2,2,3,5,5,5,5,5,8,10,11,19,19,20,20,20,20]
```

Want I want is to get a histogram that tells me something like this (I round up to the nearest power of two for occurrences):

- Number of elements occurring 1 time: 5
- Number of elements occurring 2 times: 1
- Number of elements occurring 4 times: 2
- Number of elements occurring 8 times: 1

I don't need to be able to ask "how often does element `n` occur?", although this seems like the main thing that people do with Count Sketch. Is there a variant of Count Sketch that can give me a histogram like the one I'm looking for?

Comment: Just to make sure: your input is streaming data?

Comment: @LiorKogan Yes. Although I would be enlightened even to see a solution for non-streaming data, as long as it can still run in `O(n)` time.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19211453/cumulative-frequency-table-with-creation-in-linear-or-better-than-linear-complex

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified more. Using a hashmap takes `O(n)` space, where n is the number of distinct elements. I was hoping to avoid that, even though it means my histogram cannot be totally correct.